# Using Selenium Webdriver to obtain the active status of an element?

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver

We've got a new page we're automating, and some of the features coming through with the bootstrap template are causing some complications for automation.

Traditionally, with a checkbox or radio button, we use a tag to identify it:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "body [autotag='prf_rd_1']")]
        private IWebElement myElement;
```

At which point you can use element.isSelected in Webdriver code to see if it's ticked.

However, with bootstrap devs have changed to use a button which is either active or not active, eg:

```
<button class="btn" autotag="prf_bt1" btn-radio="availabilityType.key" ng-model="model.availability.time" type="button"> … </button>

<button class="btn **active**" autotag="prf_bt1" btn-radio="availabilityType.key" ng-model="model.availability.time" type="button"> … </button>
```

(Hmm, not sure how to highly the word active in a code snippet, if anyone knows please feel free to edit)

So, now we can't look for 'isSelected', as it doesn't work like a checkbox.

Does anyone have a code sample for determining whether a button has active class in its css, without using XPATH?  Currently we would use the CssSelector as above, and this way elements can move, text can change but as long as that autotag is still there, it's all good.  However, I'm unclear how I could do this AND look for other CSS (the class) at the same time to determine if it's active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just want a CSS selector that can locate an element that *contains* a specific value inside a specific attribute, in this case, it's `class`.

That's easy, an elaborate way to do this would be:

```
button[class*='active']
```

The `*=` is an attribute wildcard, allowing you to say "where A is somewhere inside that attribute's value".

To specifically look for a `button` that has a `class` that contains `active` **and** have an `auto-tag` attribute which is set to `prf_bt1`:

```
button[class*='active'][auto-tag='prf_bt1']
```

Comment: I actually prefer `button[class~='active']`  a little bit more lenient.  But even better - `button.active` `:D`

Comment: Yep, I can do that if I'm just looking for class, but in this case I'm looking for the autotag attribute with cssselector, and THEN want to know if it's got an active tag in the class as well.  It's the "in one step" bit that I'm struggling with,.

Comment: @Arran aha, yes, that's what I've been looking for. Didn't realise the dual-attribute search was an option.  Will give that a go, thanks

Comment: Have found I can also do FindElementsbyCSS(theattribute + active) where active is ".active".  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of these methods to get status of an element,

```
getAttribute  
getCssValue  
isEnabled
```

You can get more details on these methods at [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html).

Comment: Yes, I've used all these methods in the past. However in this case I'm already using cssselector to find items with the autotag attribute, and then want to know if the element obtained has an active class or not.  Could you elaborate how you would use those methods to achieve this?